# How to merge cells vertically in outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-table, html-email

Is it possible to merge two cells vertically and keep the text in Outlook 2016?

1.
[image: Step 1]

2.Click merge cells

[image: Click merge cells]

3. Text disappears
   [image]

Alternatively, it appears impossible to get this table to appear correctly in an email (in notepad++, choose Run/Send via Outlook), however when viewed in a browser, it appears fine.

```
<html>
<table class="tg" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Type</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Power</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Torque</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l" rowspan="2">Car</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">120hp</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">100nm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="2">Has 4 wheels<br></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Finally, I understand as of Outlook 2007, it uses Word (!) to render html, not Internet Explorer. However when viewing this html in word, the title "Car" appears, but not in outlook.

**EDIT**: I just rebooted and let office install its updates and now the original emails and table merge work properly.

Comment: Stay away from rowspan and colspan. As you have found out its buggy in Outlook. Try this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZcQf.png. The red boxes shows how the table structure should be so it works on all email clients.

Comment: Thanks, how do I achieve that structure without using row span?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to achieve this. Removing the col spans and rowspans you will need to resort to more tables but you can be sure it will render the same across all devices.

```html
<table class="tg" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Type</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <th>Power</th><th>Torque</th>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l" align="center" valign="middle">

      <table class="tg" border="1">
      <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">Car</td>
      </tr>
      </table>

    </td>
    <td>
      <table border="1">
      <tr>
      <td>120hp</td><td>100nm</td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      <table class="tg" border="1">
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-yw4l">Has 4 wheels<br></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this is what you were after.

Cheers